# PostgreSQL leaving headers blank while importing CSV

Tags: postgresql, csv, pgadmin

I'm trying to import a CSV file with column names "Zip Code", "2010 Population", "Land-Sq-Mi" and "Density per Sq Mile" into my test table, which is named derp--that's why I have the drop statement at the beginning, so I don't replicate any rows and can start clean in each iteration.

Code is as follows:

```
DROP TABLE derp;
CREATE TABLE public.derp("Zip Code" varchar, "2010 Population" integer, "Land-Sq-Mi"  numeric, "Density Per Sq Mile" numeric);
COPY derp("Zip Code", "2010 Population", "Land-Sq-Mi", "Density Per Sq Mile")
FROM '/home/michael/PycharmProjects/cmsDataProject/Zipcode-ZCTA-Population-Density-And-Area-Unsorted.csv'
DELIMITER',' 
CSV HEADER;
```

This does a fine job of importing the actual data, but it leaves the column headers blank in the pgadmin III data view. I looked at the source file in Nano--the headers are there, and if they weren't the query would have thrown a syntax error telling me that there was no relation for the column I was trying to import into.

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I would like pgadmin III data view to display the header names, and possibly a way to verify that the columns are actually named even if they aren't being imported and not displayed. To reiterate, every row after the headers is intact and in view, just the header row is blank.

Edit 2: When I `CREATE TABLE public.derp();` and then manually add the columns, they show correctly in the data view. Something about the multi-line query statement was causing the breakage.

Comment: What result do you have? What result do you want?

Comment: @newman post updated to reflect what I have versus what I want.

Comment: pgadmin show column headers as columns name that you use on table create. In COPY CSV HEADER mean that first line contains name of columns for insert data to correct columns. If

Comment: @newman either the rest of your comment got lost, or I'm not following at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So pgadmin is not showing the column names but it's showing the data?

If you open a table in pgadmin, then alter the table, but keep the table window open, it seems to lose the column names.

Close the window with the table. Click the tables icon in the pgadmin tree view and refresh the tables, and reopen the table window.